# Converting .sis to .apk

Tags: android

I have worked on Symbian for a while and now working on Blackberry and Android. Are we able to convert .apk to .sis or vice versa, so that we can save lot of developement time. is there any converter like that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Symbian uses compiled packages whereas Android runs on Java. It wouldn't be possible to convert between the two, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  As tjameson alludes to, Symbian uses C++, while Android is Java-like.  Further, they have completely different APIs (Symbian OS or Qt vs. Android/Java libraries)

Even if there were a converter, it would yield very poor results, since the two platforms have different capabilities, security models, and GUI conventions.

Answer (score -1):

no, there's no way a game,software for symbian to android apk unless it was built for android apk, its not as simple as 3gp/mp4 converted to mp3... yet, it was a file extract system, also it have its own unique system operating, as symbian can run 2 type of application as follows: Nokia s40 (Java MIDP) and Nokia s60 (Java Midp + symbian series/alike windows xp,vista n 7 function), so it is true that it wouldn't be... it is sad that we can't play explode arena on android tho :(